# Setting up iAd Network for testing application

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator, admob, iad

I have setup a test application using Admob Mediation service. The application functions fine, but I receive an error from iAd incorrectly configured. I think this is due to it not being correctly/completely setup in ITunes connect.

As I am new to this, I am unsure, the error doesn't matter at the moment but I would like to setup iAd in this test application and see what control I have over iAd and the Ads served by this platform.

I have logged into iTunes connect and my contract for iAd is setup completely.

However, when I login to iTunes connect I see no option for iAd Network as this is detailed in the guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/3_OverviewofiTunesConnect/OverviewofiTunesConnect.html

When I go to Manage New Apps (in Itunes connect) then Add New App > this suggests submitting an app to the app store. I just want access to setup iAd for a testing application at the moment, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the app to submit to the appstore, just don't submit it... you can use a dummy screenshot and filler text for a description in the mean time (it can be edited later) then go to the apps main info page and click the blue button saying "setup iAd network". Also sometimes with iTunesConnect contracts you have to wait some time before they start working... when I first signed up in 2008 I believe I had to wait a month before I could even upload my first app because of banking contracts (they don't do that anymore though)

**Also make sure you included the iAd Framework and you have imported it in your .h file

Good luck!!!

Comment: Thanks, I have done this and the app is in the status - Prepare for upload. I have then setup iAd network but it says showing testing ads. Is there no way to configure the iAd network and receive live ads when testing on simulator?

Comment: Oh, I could never get the ads to work in the simulator... sorry!

Comment: Yes :) They do! But they show test ads... and also sometimes the ads don't show but this is by design... because in the real world when it's live sometimes there are no ads to show or maybe the user has low internet connection. So they do this so you can program the code to only display the ads when they are showing 0:) ... (If you don't do this you go against their guidelines and risk app rejection)

Comment: Sure, I get the test ads which are always adverts about iAd... I was wondering if they actually show other ads which are test ads, I guess not...? I also receive the no ads shown and an error being received as expected thanks

Comment: As Albert said above, test ads will show in simulator and on a test device.  Apple will send real ads to the app once it is in production.  It is all by design.